# How to solve a system of equations which contains symbols in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve those four equations for "p, x, y, z," , which contains two parameters "b", "a", and I have used *solve* command as shown in the code:

```
clc,clear;

syms  p x y z b a
 
eqn1 = (1)*p  + (exp(0.5*b^(1/3)))*x + (exp(-0.25*b^(1/3)) * cos(0.25*sqrt(3)*b^(1/3)))*y + (exp(-0.25*b^(1/3)) * sin(0.25*sqrt(3)*b^(1/3)))*z == 0;

eqn2 = (1)*p  + (exp(-0.5*b^(1/3)))*x + (exp(0.25*b^(1/3)) * cos(0.25*sqrt(3)*b^(1/3)))*y - (exp(0.25*b^(1/3)) * sin(0.25*sqrt(3)*b^(1/3)))*z == 0;

eqn3 = (b^(1/3)*exp(0.5*b^(1/3))+a*b^(2/3)*exp(0.5*b^(1/3)))*x + (-.866*b^.333*sin(.433*b^.333)*exp(-.25*b^.333)-.5*cos(.433*b^.333)*b^.333*exp(-.25*b^.333) + a(-.5*b^.666*cos(.433*b^.333)*exp(-.25*b^.333)+.866*b^.666*sin(.433*b^.333)*exp(-.25*b^.333)))*y + (.866*cos(.433*b^.333)*b^.333*exp(-.25*b^.333)-.5*b^.333*sin(.433*b^.333)*exp(-.25*b^.333)+a(-.5*b^.666*sin(.433*b^.333)*exp(-.25*b^.333)-.866*b^.666*cos(.433*b^.333)*exp(-.25*b^.333)))*z == 0;
                                                                 
eqn4 = (b^(1/3)*exp(-0.5*b^(1/3))-a*b^(2/3)*exp(-0.5*b^(1/3)))*x + (.866*b^.333*sin(.433*b^.333)*exp(.25*b^.333)-.5*cos(.433*b^.333)*b^.333*exp(.25*b^.333) - a(-.5*b^.666*cos(.433*b^.333)*exp(.25*b^.333)-.866*b^.666*sin(.433*b^.333)*exp(.25*b^.333)))*y + (.866*cos(.433*b^.333)*b^.333*exp(.25*b^.333)+.5*b^.333*sin(.433*b^.333)*exp(.25*b^.333)-a(.5*b^.666*sin(.433*b^.333)*exp(.25*b^.333)-.866*b^.666*cos(.433*b^.333)*exp(.25*b^.333) ))*z == 0;
                                                                       
sol = solve([eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, eqn4 ], [p, x, y, z]);
pSol = sol.p
xSol = sol.x
ySol = sol.y
zSol = sol.z
```

, but it keeps showing errors, would you please suggest any solution to this issue.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: @ThomasSablik, this error
"Error using sym/subsref (line 49)
Error using maplemex
Error, (in MTM:-subsref) indices must be positive integers, got
-.500000000000000000*exp(-.250000000000000000*b^.333000000000000018)*cos(.432999999999999996*b^.333000000000000018)*b^.666000000000000036+.865999999999999992*exp(-.250000000000000000*b^.333000000000000018)*sin(.432999999999999996*b^.333000000000000018)*b^.666000000000000036 "

Comment: _"indices must be positive integers"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at this :

```
eqn3 = (b^(1/3)*exp(0.5*b^(1/3))+a*b^(2/3)*exp(0.5*b^(1/3)))*x + (-.866*b^.333*sin(.433*b^.333)*exp(-.25*b^.333)-.5*cos(.433*b^.333)*b^.333*exp(-.25*b^.333) + a(-.5*b^.666*cos(.433*b^.333)*exp(-.25*b^.333)+.866*b^.666*sin(.433*b^.333)*exp(-.25*b^.333)))*y + (.866*cos(.433*b^.333)*b^.333*exp(-.25*b^.333)-.5*b^.333*sin(.433*b^.333)*exp(-.25*b^.333)+a(-.5*b^.666*sin(.433*b^.333)*exp(-.25*b^.333)-.866*b^.666*cos(.433*b^.333)*exp(-.25*b^.333)))*z == 0;
```

I pick one of the wrong parts out, 4 in total.

```
a(-.5*b^.666
```

You see, if `a(index)` exists, `index` must be a positive integer. However, in your code the value of `-.5*b^.666*cos(.433*b^.333)*exp(-.25*b^.333)+.866*b^.666*sin(.433*b^.333)*exp(-.25*b^.333)` might not be a positive integer. And A may not even be a matrix, let alone an index.

Plus, before you post your question, you' d better check the basic grammar issues to save each other's time.